# connecting to ftp server with basic-ftp quits connection immediately

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, ftp

I'm using basic-ftp to connect to a ftp server but I encountered the error below:

```bash
Connected to myip:21 (No encryption)
< 220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
220-You are user number 1 of 50 allowed.
220-Local time is now 16:52. Server port: 21.
220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.

> AUTH TLS
< 234 AUTH TLS OK.

> QUIT
```

It appears that the connection is successful but it quits immediately and triggers the catch block.

```js
      const client = new ftp.Client();
      client.ftp.verbose = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';
      try {
        await client.access({
          host: process.env.FTP_HOST,
          user: process.env.FTP_USER,
          password: process.env.FTP_PASSWORD,
          port: parseInt(process.env.FTP_PORT ?? '21'),
          secure: true,
        });
        console.log('connected');
        client.close();
        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Connexion réussie' });
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ message: "Erreur lors de l'upload" });
      }
```

This is the error message:
`Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: IP: 5.134.14.180 is not in the cert's list`

Answer (score 0):

TLS typically uses the certificate for authentication. The client generally sends the target hostname as a [TLS SNI](https://www.cloudflare.com/en-gb/learning/ssl/what-is-sni/), the server matches this against the virtual hosts it supports, then responds with the correct certificate. The client then compares the target hostname to the [CN](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/what-is-common-name/) and/or [SANs](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/what-is-common-name/#common-name-vs-subject-alternative-name), and if it matches then it makes sure that the certificate is signed by a [CA](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/how-to-determine-certificate-authority/) that it already trusts. If all that works, then the authentication step completes.

It sounds like you are connecting by IP address to a host with a certificate with names in the CN/SANs. Try connecting to one of the names and you'll likely get further.